# Using agrep to match columns

Tags: r

I am trying to match up peoples names but also want a match when names are abbreviated, so for example using grep wouldn't match up Joe Bloggs and Joseph Blogs but i need something that will be able to match them up. It looks like agrep might be what I after here but I'm unsure of how that world work. Heres what im trying to do (all these should match up);

```
names1
name             from
joe bloggs       UK
zach stephens    CAN
harry smith      UK
yu wang          CHI
james stephens   UK

names2
name                 nationality
joseph bloggs          NA
zachary stephens       NA
harrison smith         NA
wang yu                NA
james david stephens   NA
```

So U want to use the names to match up and will the nationality column in names2. Obviously grep would not match on any of these due to the slight differences in name, from reading online agrep is what im looking for here but i also need to set the distance of how far to search from the original name without letting all the characters match

Comment: You should consider using `stringdist_join` from the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Comment: @LMc Ok, can't say I'm familiar with that so I'll have to take a look into it

Answer (score 1):

Note: by default, this is an inner join. You can specify the `mode` argument if you want a different join type.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

stringdist_join(names2, names1, 
                by = "name", 
                method = "cosine", 
                distance_col = "dist", 
                max_dist = 0.15)
```

There are many methods of fuzzy matching implemented, but here we match using cosine similarity. Using the distance functions from `fuzzyjoin` a value closer to zero indicates *more* similar. I included the distance measure in the output for you to see, but you can exclude it if it is not needed.

Here I specified `max_dist` after looking at the output and seeing this cutoff gave perfect separation between matches and non-matches. Another possibility is to specify `max_dist=1`, this will return the cartesian product of names from `names1` and `names2`. You can then group by `name.x` and take the row where `dist` is minimized. This is slower computationally and should be avoided if you have a large data set.

**Output**

```
               name.x nationality         name.y from       dist
1        joseph bloggs          NA     joe bloggs   UK 0.08029099
2     zachary stephens          NA  zach stephens  CAN 0.06341419
3       harrison smith          NA    harry smith   UK 0.11922899
4              wang yu          NA        yu wang  CHI 0.00000000
5 james david stephens          NA james stephens   UK 0.10920133
```